# Best practice - C# Dictionary item access

Tags: c#, design-patterns

Here is my code

```
public void DoSomethin(IEnumerable<string> values)
{
    Dictionary<string, string> d = GetDictionary();

    foreach(var value in values)
    {
         if(d.Contains(value))
         {
              //Do something
         }else{
              // What now ?
         }
    }
}
```

The value collection is comming from a web interface,so there could be some invalid data.

My question is, what should be done, if the dictionary doesn't contain the current value ?

Should be thrown an exception or just skipped the current loop ?

This code is generating rows for a grid..

Comment: That is surely up to your requirements/design? which we don't know? btw, d.TryGetValue may be easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exceptions are for communicating with software, not with users. Given what you've shown us, I can't think of a single situation in which it would be appropriate to throw an exception.

Since you're generating a grid, this code should create an empty cell or display 'not provided' in the cell, depending on what you want the user to experience.

If you can't proceed without the value, display an error message to the user.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the [TryGetValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb347013.aspx) which will return null if the item doesn't exist.  I would avoid exceptions for this type of thing as they can be costly.

Comment: The questions isn't how to handle a missing value at a low level, it seems to be in regards to how the application should continue upon encountering this situation, which we cannot answer provided the information that has been given.

Answer (score 1):

> My question is, what should be done, if the dictionary doesn't contain the current value ? Should be thrown an exception or just skipped the current loop ?

You haven't given us enough domain information to answer that.  It really comes down to the requirements/expectations of your program.  Is missing data an expected circumstance?  Can your program deal with that and still meet its own requirements?  If the answer is yes, then handle it appropriately.  If the answer is no, then it is a fatal exception and your hands are tied.

Answer (score 1):

It depends, there are 3 possiblities:

1. If user should know something is wrong and you wanna cancel row generation- throw something
2. if user should know he entered something wrong and you don't wanna cancel row generation - add all not found values to a list and show them as errors.
3. If user shouldn't know if something is wrong just ignore them.